# Searching is not happening with dirPaginate directive in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dirpagination

I made a list using Angular JS (1.x). I have to implement pagination, so I am using [dirPaginate](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) for this purpose.

Now I need to put a search box above the list box to enable the user to search among the list items, so I am using filters also.

The problem is that whatever I search for in the search box, it doesn't return anything in the search result even though the searched item exist in the list.

Below is my code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/>

<div dir-paginate="data in fiteredResults = (topics | toArray | 
                   naturalSort | filter:searchText) | itemsPerPage: 2" 
     class="row topic group" 
     id="topic_{{data.$key | metricNameClass}}">

     <div class="col-md-12">
       {{data.$key}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a plnkr